# flask security auth_token_required - token authentication

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I've successfully implemented token auth and protect my rest web service method with it - this is great approach.

Now I have trouble to access user data from token - like ID - in order to manipulate with it in accessed (protected) rest service method.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the `current_user` which will reflect the currently authenticated user for the current request.

```
from flask_security import current_user, auth_token_required

@app.route('/')
@auth_token_required
def view():
    print current_user.id
```